# How to access System.Drawing ie System.Drawing.Common in Asp.Net Core 3

Tags: asp.net-core, nuget, system.drawing, asp.net-core-3.0

I'm in the process of converting an Asp.Net Core 2.2 Website that targeted the Full Framework to an Asp.Net Core 3.1 App that targets .Net Core 3.1. I'm a bit unclear about dependencies related to System.Drawing and how to fulfill them.

My project uses System.Drawing and when compiling under Asp.Net Core 3.1 I get this error that suggests that I add a reference to `System.Drawing.Common.dll` :

> Error CS1069: The type name 'Image' could not be found in the namespace 'System.Drawing'. This type has been forwarded to assembly 'System.Drawing.Common, Version=4.0.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' Consider adding a reference to that assembly.   1-wwwGiftOasis3 C:\Users\Ron\source\repos\wwwGiftOasis3\wwwGiftOasis3\site\seller\profile\about\s-photos.cs

In Visual Studio I don't see a way to add a reference directly to the bare `System.Drawing.Common.dll` so I assume that I should add the reference via NuGet.

In NuGet I see a `System.Drawing.Common` package which looks like what I want but it's unclear to me whether my project fulfills the dependencies:

[image]

My Project shows these dependencies:

[image]

So I have a couple questions related to all this:

1) Does the fact my the project depends on Framework `Microsoft.NETCore.App` fulfill the NuGet package's `Microsoft.NETCore.Platforms` dependency?

2) Does the fact that I intend to only run this Asp.Net Core 3.1 website on windows fulfill the NuGet package's  `Microsoft.Win32.SystemEvents` dependency?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`System.Drawing` utilizes Windows-specific APIs, and as such, is incompatible with .NET Core, which is cross-platform. Microsoft created `System.Drawing.Common` as an in-place replacement for `System.Drawing` for .NET Core. It is an exact API replacement, but performs the image operations in a cross-platform, rather than Windows-specific, way.

Long and short, yes, you just drop the NuGet into your project and go to town. There's nothing else you need to worry about.

Comment: Makes sense, but given that why would the NuGet package have a dependency on `Microsoft.Win32.SystemEvents`  which doesn't sound like something that would be on a unix platform?

Comment: Again, this is a drop-in API replacement. As such, it needs to mimic the old `System.Drawing`. This NuGet essentially translates Windows system events into appropriate things on the target plafform (i.e. Linux).

Comment: That said, MSDN's System.Drawing docs do come with a big warning that System.Drawing is not supported for asp.net. I'm not sure if using .Net Core changes that.

Comment: Adding nuGet package System.Drawing.Common worked fine with .Net Core 2.1 But isn't working well for .Net Core 2.0. I have an application using .Net Core 2.0. Any idea ?

Comment: I guess that is due to conclict between System.drawing that is provided through .netcore2.0 and system.drawing.common nuget. I'm also still working on it.

Comment: You should check Dependency on the NuGet manager. For older .net core you need an older system.drawing.common @ChetanKota